# Set focus on user Control's text box when child window is opened

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a simple WPF windows which hosts a user control. User control contains a label, TextBox and couple of buttons. OK as default button and a Cancel button. I launch this dialog/windows from my parent window. What I want to achieve is when this dialog is launched, TextBox should have input control. I have tried to set tab index to 0 but that does not seem to work.

When the window opens, I have to press tab once to get the input control in the edit box. Here is how my TextBox's xaml looks like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" AcceptsReturn="False" TabIndex="0"></TextBox>
```

Further more, I want this window to open up in centre of its parent window. I have set

```
<Window .......   WindowStyle="ToolWindow" Topmost="True" ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
```

On multiple screens the window always opens up on the primary monitor. HOw can I make it open on the parents window's centre?

P.S: Preferably I want to do this in WPF.

Comment: How are you opening the dialog exactly, seems you want modal but you're opening modeless (or with a different owner)... Also i don't see the point of having such a simple usercontrol (that doesn't seem reusable in other scenarios) being the only child in a window, why not just host all the things in the window itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question write this code:

```
public YourChildWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    YourTextBox.Focus();
}
```

For second question: You must set the `StartupLocation` of Child Window as `CenterOwner` **AND** set the `Owner` of child window as `ParentWindow` before showing the child Window. For example, write this code in the parent window:

```
Window ownedWindow = new Window();
ownedWindow.Owner = this;
ownedWindow.Show();
```

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner.aspx